# No project can be run from eclipse on Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, web-applications, webserver

When trying to create Dynamic Web project or even using old one( which used to work before) and running it on the tomcat(v8.0.35) server from my eclipse (mars.2 v4.5.2) I started getting Http status code 404 when accessing the recourse:

[image]

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>hello</display-name>
  <servlet>
        <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.javawebtutor.controller.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <display-name>RegisterServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.javawebtutor.controller.RegisterServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/RegisterServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

For reference, I have done everything step by step in this tutorial:
http://www.javawebtutor.com/articles/hibernate/mvc-appliction-using-servlet-jsp-and-hibernate.html

Java I'm using for the project is jdk1.8. For server - jre1.8
I'm 99% sure I've not deviated from the tutorial and something wrong must be with my Tomcat installation. As I mentioned it worked before on other projects I have not modified and it stopped working as well.

I have tried cleaning projects, cleaning Tomcat server, work directory, remove tomcat server, restart eclipse, add tomcat server again. I've even converted project into Maven project and tried to build with clean and install goals. Nothing helped.

Here is server location snippet:
[image]

Related answer here: [Tomcat is not deploying my web project from Eclipse](http://Tomcat%20is%20not%20deploying%20my%20web%20project%20from%20Eclipse)

And yes, I did try everything in there.

If it helps I'm developing on Win10

EDIT:
Project topology:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the limited amount of info, I suggest you do the following:

- Check if you have a login.jsp directly under your **webapp** or **webContent**(your tutorial uses this), because your welcome file in web.xml specifies this as your home page.
- Try access **http://localhost:8080/** instead of http://localhost:8080/hello/

Please provide your complete expanded project tree if the above does not solve your problem.

Also, here is one of my youtube video introducing [how to set up a running java-web app with eclipse and tomcat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcddP50PMv0). It is only a couple of minutes.
Following this tutorial makes sure you have a minimal java web project running, you can start from there if your problem cannot be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have edited my question by adding topology>
Java I'm using is v8

Comment: Like I said in my first bullet point, you should put login.jsp along with other jsp pages directly under WebContent folder. However, you have put all those pages under WebContent/WEB-INF. According to your web.xml, you should put those outside of WEB-INF and under WebContent, whew..

Comment: Good catch! Thats true, they are supposed to be under WebContent however with all the cleaning and restarting it didn't help either =/